# Jackson 2 incorrectly serializing Java java.nio.file.Path

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, resteasy

I'm using RESTEasy 3.1.0.CR3 with Tomcat 8.5.6 inside Eclipse 4.6.1, with the JSBoss resteasy-jackson2-provider. I have a simple JavaBean `FooBar` that returns a string "ID" and a `java.nio.file.Path` "path".

Jackson makes this easy to serialize to JSON. In my JAX-RS resource I simply specify `@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")`. But Jackson is not using `Path.toString()`. Instead it appears to be using `Path.toURI().toString()` or something:

```
{
  "id": "foo",
  "path": "file:///C:/Users/jdoe/bar"
}
```

Why!?? And more importantly, how can I get Jackson to simply use the `toString()` version of `Path`?

Here is my project dependency tree:

```
+- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:provided
+- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
+- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:provided
+- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.1.0.CR3:compile
|  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec:jar:1.0.1.Beta1:compile
|  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs-services:jar:3.1.0.CR3:compile
|  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
|  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
|  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
|  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
|  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
+- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-servlet-initializer:jar:3.1.0.CR3:compile
+- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:jar:3.1.0.CR3:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.3:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.3:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.3:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.3:compile
|     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.8.3:compile
|     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.3:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
\- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
```

Note that it is *not* acceptable for me to add annotations to my `FooBar` class, which is a domain model class that should have no coupling with the RESTful API serialization details.

I want a simple way to hook into Jackson2 in RESTEasy and modify the serialization of a `Path` property value without modifying my class or writing a custom serializer for my class.

Comment: Can you share Jackson version because atleast 2.7.0 uses ToStringSerializer to serialize Path.

Comment: I'm using [`org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.1.0.CR3`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.resteasy%7Cresteasy-jackson2-provider%7C3.1.0.CR3%7Cjar).

Comment: Hmm but can you can provide version of jackson-core that is resolved by your project

Comment: I added a complete dependency tree for you.

Comment: You are using 2.8.3 in this version they have added [NioPathSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ext/NioPathSerializer.html) with calls path.toUri().toString(). Try degrading version of jackson to 2.7.X

Comment: I don't want to degrade. Jackson is configurable, right? I should just be able to tell Jackson to use the string serializer for paths, right? How can I do that in a central location, preferably in a JAX-RS way, without touching my `FooBar` class?

Comment: Hmm, let me check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class will override default Jackson2JsonProvider help you to configure ObjectMapper, according to you needs, like serializer for Path.class is overriden to ToStringSerializer from NioPathSerializer.

```
@Provider
@Consumes({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
@Produces({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
public class CustomJacksonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {

  public CustomJacksonProvider(){
    super(configureMapper(new ObjectMapper()));
  }

  public static ObjectMapper configureMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    SimpleModule m = new SimpleModule("PathToString");
    m.addSerializer(Path.class,new ToStringSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(m);
    return mapper;
  }

}
```

**Or you can use ContextResolver also for the same which will use ResteasyJackson2Provider(*RestEasy default*)**

```
@Provider
@Consumes({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
@Produces({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
public class CustomJacksonProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

  final ObjectMapper mapper;

  public CustomJacksonProvider(){
    mapper = new JsonMapperConfigurator(new ObjectMapper(), JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.DEFAULT_ANNOTATIONS)
            .getConfiguredMapper();
    SimpleModule m = new SimpleModule("PathToString");
    m.addSerializer(Path.class, new ToStringSerializer());
  }

  @Override
  public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
    return mapper;
  }
}
```

Add this to you `web.xml` irrespective of approch you use:

```
    <context-param>
       <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
       <param-value>package.to.CustomJacksonProvider</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

If you are not using a `web.xml` file, return the provider class in your JAX-RS application's `Application.getClasses()` method.

Hope this helps.

**Edited**:

Also, you might miss JAXB annotation support in this implementation you have to configure that manually, because `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` doesn't look  for Resolver/provider of `JsonMapperConfigurator`. Use `JsonMapperConfiguration` with  mapper in `CustomJackosnProvider` along with  `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.DEAFULT_ANNOATIONS`. Ideally, since there is no provision to provide  `JsonMapperConfiguration` Resolver/Provider and RestEasy's jackson provider doesn't expose arg constructor, provider is best bet. Since they taken this decision, ideally they should not do any customization in `ResteasyJackson2Provider`. Also, only functionality in `ResteasyJackson2Provider` is custom json type and better caching of mapper at class level.

**Updated code according to explanation**

Comment: So which approach would I use if I wanted to be as noninvasive as possible? It seems that in the first approach (unless I extend `ResteasyJackson2Provider`---but I want to keep RESTEasy-specific stuff out of my code) I'll throw away whatever capabilities `ResteasyJackson2Provider` might provide. Either way I seem to be creating a new `ObjectMapper`. But the code to `ResteasyJackson2Provider` seems to look up an existing `ObjectMapper`. Am I discarding some built-in functionality by creating a new one?

Comment: Woohoo---it works! Thanks so much for clearly and succinctly laying out the steps to solve this problem. (I would appreciate clarifications; see other comment.) I edited the answer to include instructions on registering the class in a non-`web.xml` configuration. And sorry I took so long to review this that the bounty was auto-awarded at 50%. You gave such a useful answer that I wanted to start another bounty just to make sure you get what you deserve, but it is forcing a very high bounty for the second one. :(

Comment: I would recommend second one because it, ContextResolver are meant for that purpose without missing any other feature provided by reasteasy

Comment: But in creating my own `ObjectMapper`, is there something I will be missing that RESTEasy was adding to its `ObjectMapper`? Or will all the `ObjectMapper`s be combined? How does it work? (Or maybe point me to documentation.)

Comment: And is `@Consumes` and `@Produces` really appropriate for a `ContextResolver` implementation? Aren't they only for message body readers and writers? Do they serve any purpose in the second example? (I now see in the JAX-RS specification they are allowed---but are they required or useful in this case? How are they used?)

Comment: Yes JacksonJsonProvider looks for MediaType also to but you can still remove them it will still pick it up, if there is no provider for that type.

Comment: Your info is wonderful, Shashank. What did you mean when you said, "Ideally, since there is no provision to provide JsonMapperConfiguration Resolver/Provider and RestEasy's jackson provider doesn't expose arg constructor, provider is best bet." Could you clarify this? What does "provider is best bet" mean?

Comment: 1) Since RestEasy only exposes non constructor, hence you can't instantiate it with your mapper. Hence missing configuration for ObjectMapper.
2) Since JsonMapperConfigurator used by JackonJsonProviderJacksonProvider  is constructed in JackonJsonProvider Constructor, so you can't provide custom JsonMapperConfigurator, therefore no scope of providing you config to mapper. Also it there was a way you need tell it that whether apply both or any one, if both which order.

Comment: Sorry for typo using mobile